# Running trend or no trend Twitter rumor project

Tags: algorithm, twitter, hadoop, trending

I'm learning about algorithms "trending topic", I have read the article by Stanislav Nikolov, Trend or No Trend: A Novel Nonparametric Method for Classifying Time Series.

I tried downloading his project in [here](https://github.com/snikolov/rumor). When I tried to run, an error occurs:

```
hduser@master:~/rumor$ ./test_detection.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test_detection.py", line 6, in <module>
    ts_viral = rumor.parsing.parse_timeseries('data/' + sys.argv[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I intend to run on a Hadoop cluster. What do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means your program needs some command line parameters. sys.argv contains the list of parameters, and since you did not give any, there was a "index out of range" error. Read the manual carefully.